# Make short key for searching filter in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, search

Can one help me to make a short key for the following procedure in Excel 2010 (ALT+DownArrow then E) . this used to go directly to search box in filter excel like shown in photo

[image]

and if some know another way to jump directly to this window of filter it is really will increase the speed of my work while searching

thank you very much

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried in order to accomplish this?

Comment: just need a short key to jump directly to searching box in sort&filter function . like while I stand on a top cell to search I should press ALT+ArrowDown than press E , I just want a short key to collect this operation

Comment: It is obvious what you WANT. My comment is asking what you have done on your own to figure this out. I'm not trying to be difficult, rather want you to understand we volunteer out time here to help when you get stuck attempting to do something, not to just do it for you. There is additional information available in the [help].

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro and assigning it a shortcut key?

Comment: yes I tried but the macro not help.. if u can do it

Comment: `Alt + down arrow + E` is the shortcut key combination for Excel to do what you want. At best you are going to save a single key stroke.

Comment: What does Alt + E do for you ??

Comment: @CharlieRB sorry for misunderstanding english not my mother tongue, but I mentioned in my post it is just for increasing speed work,  and use this when u keep have searching in excel filtering in same cell . and as u knoe the alt+down arrow it is not in suitable place to do while u use one hand on keyboard and other hand in other thing. I hope I could explain what I want, and sorry again

Comment: @Gary'sStudent what u mean it is not do what i am searching for

Comment: @CharlieRB it is but when u use one hand on keyboard it is little not stable especially when u use alt +down arrow then press e it is not in same side on keyboard as u know

Answer (score 1):

You can get this behavior with just a single mouse click.  Include the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.SendKeys "%{DOWN}f"
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Anytime you click on cell **A1,** the pull-down will occur automatically.

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: thank you it is really good but not worked 100% because it need to leave the cell and press back to activate and not jump to search box directly , I am really will appreciate that if u can update your code to be better..
and another thing this code can't be shortkey in Macro?

Comment: WOW I fixed the jumping to search box I just changed the "%{DOWN}f" to "%{DOWN}e"... but still trying to activate when I remain on same cell :(

Comment: @Monther Sadly.................the macro needs you to leave the cell and then re-enter it.

Comment: Thank you Gary you teach me more things in your answer really thanks